# Javascript Code for searching within SharePoint List Customization

Tags: list, custom-list, search-results, custom-form

Hi I am new at using Sharepoint and I have never script script before. I am trying to add a search functionality to a Custom List. When I click search it says "404 NOT FOUND"

I found this code online ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uF1kjDLk3vc&t=638s & multiple other sites)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function RedirectUrl() {
        var tb = document.getElementById("tbSearch").value;
        var cs = document.getElementById("sfield").value;
        var url = "";

        if (tb != "") {
            if (cs == "First_x0020_Name" || cs == "Last_x0020_Name" || cs == "Company_x0020_Name" || cs == "​") {
                url = "FilterField1=" + cs + "&FilterValue1=" + tb;
                window.location.href = "AllItems.aspx?" + url;
            }
            else {
                url = "FilterName=" + cs + "&FilterMultiValue=*" + tb + "*";
                window.location.href = "AllItems.aspx?" + url;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function ClearUrl() {
        window.location.href = "AllItems.aspx";
    }
        </script>Search Field: 
<select id="sfield">
<option value="Title">Site</option>

<option value="First_x0020_Name">First Name</option>
<option value="Last_x0020_Name">Last Name</option>
<option value="Company_x0020_Name">Company</option>
</select>   Search text: 
<input id="tbSearch" type="text"/><input id="btnSearch" onclick="return RedirectUrl();" type="button" value="Search"/>
<input id="btnClear" onclick="return ClearUrl();" type="button" value="Clear"/> ​​​<br/>​<br/>
```

[image: ScreenShot of List]

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering to know what could be the business requirement of having a custom search box in the list since there is out of the box search box **Find and item** search box.

However, to customize the search with custom coding you need to query the search rest API which will return the result after the search crawl or you can go with customizing the search display template.

**Why SharePoint list item does not appear in the out of the box search (Find an item)?**

Sometimes, the SharePoint list item does not appear in the SharePoint out of the box search (**Find an item**). So, we need to verify the below steps:

Go to the list setting page -> Click on the Advanced Settings

Under the **search** section :

Allow items from this list to appear in search results? **Yes**

And from the **Reindex List** section, click on the **Reindex List** button

Then run the **Full Crawl** from Central Admin.

Now search should work.

Reference screenshot:

[image: Why SharePoint list item does not appear in the search?]

Comment: I forgot to remove the out of the Box Find an Item Search box, we want to be able to search by Name and Company and using out of the box, I never get any results. Can you explain a bit more on what you mean? "you need to query the search rest api which will return the result after the search crawl or you can go with customizing the search display template" I have no clue what any of that means... I am not a developer, I been pretty much just copying and modifying codes to work for the sharepoint.

Comment: Added the steps how out of the box search(find an item) can be fixed.